# How to avoid security restrictions when handling events from a restricted AppDomain?

Tags: c#, appdomain

I'm implementing a plugin system where each plugin is running in a dedicated and strongly restricted `AppDomain`. However, plugins can send messages to the host, and the host logs them in the application.

The logging is solved by an `event` which is raised on the restricted `AppDomain` and handled in the host `AppDomain` (using a MBRO proxy class). The problem is that  as the event gets raised from the restricted `AppDomain`, that restricted security context is still in effect when my handler code executes in the host assembly in the host `AppDomain`. So at the end I cannot even log the messages to the application's standard log file for example.

How could I achieve that the host-side handler executes in the application's security context rather than the caller's one? Hope it makes sense, thank you in advance.

If it's needed I can try to provide some example code but it's quite hard, that's why it's not here.

Comment: How about the events adding the messages to some kind of queue and a thread running in the host appdomain will handle the messages from that queue.

Comment: @thehennyy Thanks for the comment, yeah that's the only way so far what I've been thinking of. Would be a bit unfortunate as in some really rare cases it can hurt consistency.

Comment: Just to let you all know, I'm about to choose a solution with a bit less indirection compared to a full async way. I'll gather the log messages during the entire plugin process and then at the end as a separate call I push them all to the application log.